# Unable to create new Facebook application for integrating Facebook in iOS app

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios5, oauth

I am using sharekit to integrate FB in my app and using xcode4. Everything was fine till I was using my old FB app's id and secret. After all being done I created a new app at developers.facebook.com and entered the new key and secret in the app, now here's what which happens, if a previous session exist in the app means a valid access token, then I am able to post on my wall but when I deleted the app from the simulator to check things from scratch then I start receiving this error instead of the login dialog:
"Sorry, the application you are using is misconfigured for Facebook integration......"
I've tried to use the same configuration as per my older apps but nothing happening. Any help would be much appreciated as I am quite much stuck with this problem. Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last 6 weeks, Facebook has changed the way session-tokens are stored (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/). ShareKit may not have implemented the new FBConnect SDK. I highly suggest implementing the SDK directly instead of using ShareKit.

Comment: Thanks for replying... I will give it a try and will post here whatever comes up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you with exactly the same error string. but now it's working with me and I can share texts in my new app, and I did nothing in the app's config. don't if this is true, but my conclusion is that facebook need some time to approve your new app.

so just wait couple of hours.

Comment: I have been waiting for almost 2-3 days. Anyways, thanks for your time